# Windows 10 doesn't refresh once my external drive is decrypted

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, bitlocker

I have three drives, `C` (where my OS is installed), `E` and `D`. All of these are encrypted with BitLocker due to a company policy.

When I start up my computer, all of these drives are encrypted, and I need to input the decryption key to unlock each one. Some programs freak out until the drives are unlocked, because they can't access their data. After these drives are unlocked, however, I can restart those programs and they're usually fine. Also, after unlocking I can use all my drives normally from Windows Explorer.

One program that frequently fails however is some weird part of Windows 10, that *sometimes* refuses to refresh and scan for new drives, even after they are unlocked.

A system that uses this part is the dialog on Settings -> System -> Storage -> "Change where new content is saved". Here is an image of it during one of those times where it just doesn't want to acknowledge that there are new drives available. You can see they're fine on explorer and `diskmgmt`.

[image]

Another system that uses this part is the Xbox app for Windows. During this bug, it will not recognize any installed games on the other drives until I reboot and get lucky.

What I wish to know is:

1. What is this "part" of Windows 10 that fails here even called? I can't just Google "bitlocker drive doesn't show up", as that is usually something else;
2. How to force this part of Windows 10 to refresh, and rescan for new drives.

Comment: “What is this "part" of Windows 10 that fails here even called?” - It’s not called anything.  Your drives should be available after you login.  Have you automatically configured the drives to mount or are you doing that manually?

Comment: I haven't configured anything special, they are mounted automatically at startup, and they work fine: You can see them on windows explorer. They are not external drives or anything (I mispoke on the question title), they're just connected to the SATA and NVME ports on my motherboard.

Comment: Are those additional drives initialized as regular Bitlocker volumes or as Bitlocker-to-go? Because Bitlocker has the functionality to automatically unlock secondary drives based on the system Bitlocker encrypted volume. May be those secondary volumes are just not linked to your primary volume so that you have to manually unlock them (which causes your problems). As your local IT if Bitlocker with automatic unlock for secondary drives is allowed in your IT environment.

Comment: They are all separate Bitlocker volumes. Each has it's own separate encryption key: I input the key for my C drive (with the OS) during boot before windows loads, and I input the key for the other drives by double-clicking them on Windows Explorer while they're locked and providing the key to the prompt then